# Function & Method description on call

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

I am trying to describe my `functions` and `class methods`.

What I mean is that you can **force** `function/methods` to control `input` and `output`values if the type of the data is the same as defined one.

Basic definition could look like this:

```
def SWE4_UT1_complex(root: os.path | PurePath) -> (float | int, str | int): ...
```

---

**First problem**

---

I am actually trying to define multiple values inside list. To be exact I want to define that `kpis` variable is a list of class instances.

```
class KPI: ... <- this is my class

input_kpis = list()

for i in json_input.kpis:
   input_kpis.append(KPI(some constructor parameters))
```

How to define that this kind of list has to be input parameter for function below:

```
def set_kpis(self, kpis: list) -> None: self.kpis = kpis
```

---

**Second problem** acutally the same

---

I have this function (it is working without problem)

```
def SWE1_RE1(self) -> dict:
    self.update_Requirements_Released()
    self.update_Requirements_Except_Obsolete()

    if self.Requirements_Except_Obsolete < 0 or self.Requirements_Released < 0:
        self.errors.append(f'There has been error in kpi SWE.1_RE1 for project {self.project}{f" and Release {self.release}." if self.release is not False else "."}',)

        return dict({
            'semi_results': {
                'Requirements_Released': self.Requirements_Released,
                'Requirements_Except_Obsolete': self.err_Requirements_Except_Obsolete
            },
            'err': 1,
            'output': f'There has been error in kpi SWE.1_RE1 for project {self.project}{f" and Release {self.release}." if self.release is not False else "."}',
        })
    elif self.Requirements_Except_Obsolete == 0:
        self.errors.append(f'There has been error in kpi SWE.1_RT1.\n'
                           f'There are no requirements for project {self.project}{f" and Release {self.release}." if self.release is not False else "."}',)
        return dict({
            'semi_results': {
                'Requirements_Released': 0,
                'Requirements_Except_Obsolete': 0
            },
            'err': 1,
            'output': f'There has been error in kpi SWE.1_RE1.\n'
                      f'There are no requirements for project {self.project}{f" and Release {self.release}." if self.release is not False else "."}',
        })
    else:
        return dict({
            'semi_results': {
                'Requirements_Released': self.Requirements_Released,
                'Requirements_Except_Obsolete': self.Requirements_Except_Obsolete
            },
            'err': 0,
            'output': round(self.Requirements_Released / self.Requirements_Except_Obsolete, 4),
        })
```

How to do the same as for the second problem with `list` full of `KPI`  but for a `dict` with specific values.

`dict` looks like this:

```
dict({
   str: dict({
           str: float | str,
           str: float | str
            }),
   str: int,
   str: float | int | str
```

---

---

I have tried multiple ways of definition. Such as `list([KPI])`, `list(KPI)`... It did not work. Maybe is it a correct way to use `[KPI]`? as a definition.

With a `dict` I have also tried multiple version but did not work. The problem was once I defined two `str: float | str` in the first `key` and the problem was **multiple same definition** or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try just defining it as `'list[KPI]'` this would be a list of KPI instances. (quotations needed around the type because: "Subscript for class "list" will generate runtime exception; enclose type annotation in quotes")

Apologies if this is not what you were asking.

Comment: It is one part of the problem. Thank you. But I was actually able to solve the second one with it.